# Why is the combination of letter and number greater than a number?

Tags: excel

I am applying an `if` comparison statement to a column. One of the cells is `E999` and something interesting happened:

```
# Assuming `E999` is in cell `A1`
=IF(A1>10000,"yes","no")
```

It returned `yes`. But it returned `#VALUE!` when I tried `=A1-1`. Why is that?

Comment: Text is greater than numbers. More examples: `="0">0`, `="a">23456789`, etc.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks! The majority of the cells in the column are numbers, and my original statement is `=IF(A1>=1,"pass", IF(A1<1,"fail","N/A"))`. How should I modify the statement so that cells contained text will return `N/A`?

Comment: You could use `ISNUMBER`.

Comment: Got it! `=IF(ISNUMBER(A1),IF(A1>1,"pass","fail"),"N/A")` works! Thanks again!

Comment: Or `IFERROR` too.

Comment: Yes! `IFERROR` with `VALUE()` works too.